# I am creating a pi calculator in python and I cannot convert 2 strings into integers for the program to work. Floats don't work either. Help please

Tags: python, string, tkinter, integer, pi

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

```
def Math_Operation():
    global pi
    pi = 3.14
    c.create_text(300, 450, text='Write your Sector\'s angle here', fill='blue', font='Aerial 25')
    c.create_text(500, 270, text='Write your Radius Length here', fill='blue', font='Aerial 10')
    mouse = Entry(window, bg='deepskyblue', fg='blue', font='Tahoma 20 bold')
    robot = Entry(window, bg='deepskyblue', fg='blue', font='Tahoma 10 bold') 
    c.create_window(300, 500, window=mouse)
    c.create_window(500, 300, window=robot)
    gotem = mouse.get()
    sike = robot.get()
    global main_1
    main_1 = int(gotem)
    global main_2
    main_2 = int(sike)

def Button_Command():
    math_good = 2 * main_2 * (main_1 / 360)  * pi
    sol = c.create_text(300, 580, text='Solution:', fill='blue', font='Tahoma 20 bold')
    c.itemconfig(sol, text='Solution:' + str(math_good), fill='blue', font='Tahoma 20 bold')
```

Comment: It looks like you're getting the values about a millisecond after creating the widgets. You need to wait to get the values until you are ready to use them.

Comment: I see that. Thank you!

Comment: It still isn't working though.

Comment: YA BUNCH OF BLOODY LEGENDS IT'S WORKING NOW!